# Unexpected type(s):(int, int)Possible type(s):(SupportsIndex, str)(slice, Iterable[str]) error in Python

Tags: python, pycharm, typeerror

```
student_height = input("Input a list of student height: ").split()
sum_of_height = 0
num_of_students = 0
average_height = 0

for n in range(0, len(student_height)):
    student_height[n] = int(student_height[n])
print(student_height)

for h in student_height:
    sum_of_height += h
print(f"The total height of students is {sum_of_height}")

for numb in student_height:  # Here, every time a value is assigned to numb, 1 is added to the num_of_students.
    num_of_students += 1  # 1 keeps getting added to the num_of_students until all values have been assigned to numb.
print(f"The total number of students are {num_of_students}")

average_height = round(sum_of_height / num_of_students)
print(f"The average height is {average_height}")
```

I am getting `Unexpected type(s):(int, int)Possible type(s):(SupportsIndex, str)(slice, Iterable[str])` this error, on this line:
`student_height[n] = int(student_height[n])`

I am using PyCharm, and the code is working perfectly, but I don't like errors in my IDE. It would be a great help if someone could solve this problem.

Comment: Can you provide the input you are supplying to the program?

Comment: @Khalil The input can be any integer but for instance, I used: 165 170 175

Comment: I ran the program with multiple inputs but none resulted in an error

Comment: @Khalil I am using PyCharm, it is showing this as an error.

Comment: This "error" is only related to the static type checking done in Pycharm. There's no runtime error.

Comment: @Blckknght Is there any way to solve this error? Errors in IDE doesn't look good you know.

Comment: The main issue is that you're changing the type of `student_type` part way through the program. Static type checking wants each variable to have only a single type, and it's not clever enough to recognize that you're converting the whole list from containing strings to integers, since you're doing it gradually. The best option would probably be to use a separate variable for the list of integers (or do the conversion all in one line, so you never save the list of strings anywhere).

Comment: @Blckknght How can I do the conversion in one line? Given that I must use for loop

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're seeing is with the static type checker. It doesn't like that you're gradually changing the types of the items in the `student_height` list. While that first loop is running, you'll have a mixture of strings and integers in the list, and the type checker thinks that might be invalid. It's not clever enough to understand that you're converting *all* the values from strings to integers.

There are a few ways you could work around the limitations of the static type checker. One would be to put the integer values into a different list than you used for the string values (which I'd do with a list comprehension):

```
student_height_strs = input("Input a list of student height: ").split()
student_height_ints = [int(s) for s in student_height_strs]
```

If you need an explicit `for` statement, rather than a comprehension, you can do that too, you'll just need to annotate the empty list you start with, so the type checker knows it will contain integers:

```
student_height_strs = input("Input a list of student height: ").split()
student_height_ints: list[int] = []                   # annotate with list[int]
for s in student_height_strs:
    student_height_ints.append(int(s))
```

If you don't want two variables, you could do the conversion to int immediately upon gathering the input, rather than as part of a second step. This could get pretty long, if you do it all in one line:

```
student_height = [int(s) for s in input("Input a list of student height: ").split()]
```

That last version is the shortest code, but might be doing too much to be easily "readable" unless you already know what its purpose is. While we think of code being written for the computer to run, it's often *also* being written for other programmers (or yourself, later, after you've forgotten the details of the implementation) to read and understand later.